# Integrar Template Admin LTE no Angular 6

Tags: angular, adminlte

Estou tentando integrar o adminlte no meu projeto, mas  não consegui

É como se ele não encontrasse os arquivos

Já dei o `npm i admin-lte --save-dev`

Já adicionei os arquivos no angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"]
          },
```

Em dois lugares no mesmo arquivo

Já segui [este](https://pt.linkedin.com/pulse/criando-um-projeto-angular-4-com-template-adminlte-soares-bentes) tutorial e nada

Estou começando agora com angular

Não tem nada ainda no style.css padrão, porque não sei o que é para adicionar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**[EDIT 1]**

Realmente depois que eu parei e dei novamente um ng serve mostrou.

Só que estamos quase lá

Agora ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ja parou o servidor e subiu de novo? da um rebuild, as vezes não compilou dieito o projeto, ve se sobe algum erro no log do `ng server` verifica se os arquivos estão no diretorio correto, ja tive problemas com isso, vai no console e olha todas as requisições que deram erro e tenta arrumar, as que são de arquivos por exemplo `.js`, `.css`, `.scss`

Comment: e todas as pastas `node_modules/` estão em um nivel acima! você precisa subir um nivel `../node_modules` em todos os `styles[]` e `scripts[]`,da uma conferida nos diretorios!

Comment: Realmente, só que ainda não está daquele jeito, lembrando que eu uso esse template com Laravel, adicionando os arquivos necessários e funciona direitinho,

Comment: Deu certo @HebertLima! Pode adicionar como resposta, na verdade, o bootstrap que eu estava utilizando era diferente do template, eu importei o do template e funcionou depois de sua dica. Porque na verdade eu só importava e atualizava a página e não dava o `ng serve` novamente.

Comment: E também estava importando os arquivos do caminho errado

Comment: https://github.com/TwanoO67/ngx-admin-lte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive problemas tambem ao utilizar temas prontos, estava relacionado ao diretorio errado, de acordo com o seu `angular.cli` os diretorios estavam apontando para o local errado:

`"node_modules/",`

que deveria ser:

`"../node_modules/",`

sempre que fizer alguma alteração no `angular.cli` é necessário recompilar o projeto com `ng server` para que sejam aplicadas as novas alterações.

Comment: Realmente eu não estava recompilando. Quanto aos arquivos, na verdade era a pasta que estava errada, mas o inicio continuou do mesmo jeito. Porque o angular 6 não vem mais com angular.cli.json e sim com angular.json na raiz, e devido a isso ao referenciar os arquivos na pasta `node_modules` não foi preciso mais iniciar com os dois pontos antes. Portanto usando `"node_modules/..."` também deu certo

Comment: mas vejo que o único problema mesmo são os caminhos estarem errados, você precisa ver todos os arquivos/diretorios que dão `404` no console/network vai te ajudar a encontrar esses arquivos

Comment: É porque depois do node_modules o resto estava tudo errado rsrs

Comment: conseguiu arrumar?!

Comment: Sim. Muito obrigado!